# Running Quantum ESPRESSO on a GPU in Windows

Tags: quantum-espresso, high-performance-computing, graphical-processing-unit, windows-operating-system

I have been using BURAI GUI for Quantum ESPRESSO for the calculation of optical properties of ZnSe. While running calculations I observed that my laptop's GPU was not even being used and I am a bit confused. I am currently using a gaming laptop, predator which has 4 cores, 8 logical processes, and 2 GPUs (Intel and Nvidia), 16GB RAM and a few other specifications (it's not even comparable to a cluster but it is the best I have at the moment). How do I utilize my GPUs for better and faster computations?

Thanks, this forum has been one of the most helpful things over the past couple of days.

Comment: +1. Just please take a careful look at [all the edits I made](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/posts/6126/revisions), and the tags I added, so no one has to do this next time!

Comment: Oh sorry, I will keep this all in mind next time before posting

Comment: Note that there are two versions of quantum espresso, one is GPU-enabled and the other one isn't. Please check that the version you are using is GPU-enabled. Did you install it with an installer, or compile it yourself?

Comment: I used the installer and did not compile it myself. I actually used the advanced soft corp one which gives the compiled binary. How do I know whether my version is gpu enabled or not?

Comment: Is the GPU-enabled one supported on windows? I guess it isnt.

Comment: @ParmeetSinghEP066 Check the soft corp website, maybe it has more information. Also, do you have CUDA and Nvidia drivers installed? They are required for most GPU-driven softwares to run. If it still doesn't work, you will have to compile from source using CUDA. (Also note that on this site, if you want to respond to someone's comment, you have to notify them using `@`, otherwise they won't know)

Comment: I think my drivers are up to date so that is probably not the problem. I can not find any mention of GPU enabled or not enabled on the soft corp git repo plus the source that they used for compilation also does not have any mention but there is another repo for GPU enabled versions so this one probably isn't GPU enabled. Also, can you give me a little more info on how to compile the source code according to my laptop using CUDA and other stuff(super new to all this).  But at least some people must have compiled QE for windows, isn't there any binary file on the web for that @ShoubhikRMaiti

Comment: @AnoopANair it is possible to compile the source code for windows, right ?? And I think it might work if I do it from - https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e-gpu/-/releases/qe-gpu-6.7
Plus the speed will also increase right, as compared to just CPU?

Comment: Hmm I can't find any compiled QE with GPU for windows from a google search, but its possible there are binaries. To compile QE, you need compilers and CUDA toolkit on your PC. You can try using the mingw64 compilers (follow the instructions on this site: https://www.msys2.org/ , make sure to install the mingw64 version, not the msys2 version of compilers). Compiling might be very difficult or impossible depending on how they have written the software. You can ping me on chat (with @), and I will help as much as I can: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117642/quantum-espresso

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti I will do that. But, before are there compiled binaries for GPU enabled version for Linux, if yes I might just download Linux using a virtual environment.

Comment: May I recommend installing Linux on a dual boot? It is generally faster than a virtual machine, because there is no virtualisation layer.

Comment: Nice to see a lot of discussion here, but I'd recommend the Quantum ESPRESSO chat room (or the HPQC one if you want to talk more about dual booting than about Quantum ESPRESSO) if you get the prompt asking you to move the discussion to chat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a Quantum Espresso expert, but I'll try to answer this as best I can. There are two aspects to this answer: 1) whether you have a GPU-enabled version of Quantum Espresso; and 2) whether you should use your GPUs anyway.

**GPU port of Quantum Espresso**

Using GPUs effectively requires substantial changes to the source code (e.g. OpenACC, OpenMP5, CUDA-Fortran), and so you need to make sure you are using a version of Quantum Espresso which has those changes. You will also need a compiler which understands the GPU additions, which probably means the NVIDIA compiler.

The previous GPU project was led by Filippo Spiga and was very quick, but made heavy use of CUDA-Fortran (only supported by NVIDIA) and I think it evolved into a separate branch, and it and the "main" Quantum Espresso diverged significantly.

https://github.com/fspiga/qe-gpu

There is a new GPU port of Quantum Espresso which is intended to stay "in sync" with the main developments. This has been released, but I'm not sure what state it's in -- it may still be a test release.

https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e-gpu/releases

Regardless, you will need the NVIDIA Fortran compiler and the CUDA toolkit (both are free). You will not be able to use Intel's compilers and I doubt that you can use GNU's either.

**GPUs for DFT simulations**

The GPUs which people usually use for DFT simulations are not graphics cards, they are dedicated compute-platforms (GPGPUs) which use technology based on graphics cards.

The "built-in" Intel GPU is unlikely to be useful; it has relatively low performance, it probably has no fast, dedicated RAM, and it is unlikely to be supported by your compiler. It is also very difficult to program for two different kinds of GPUs in the same system, and I doubt either QE or the compiler would cope.

The NVIDIA GPU probably has a good headline performance, and some fast, dedicated RAM, but I'm confident that it will only support up to single-precision arithmetic in hardware. Accurate DFT simulations rely on double-precision, and whilst the cards can emulate this in software it is extremely slow.

Much of the speed of a GPGPU is only attainable at all because they also have dedicated, high bandwidth memory (e.g. HBM2), which may not be true of a laptop model. You typically want a lot of dedicated RAM as well, which most consumer cards do not have.

If we look at the NVIDIA GPU-based offerings, you end up looking at a Titan or Tesla card before you have enough fast RAM and any significant double-precision performance for DFT simulations. Both of these have error-corrected (ECC) RAM, which I also consider important to getting reliable, publishable results (this goes for CPU calculations too, of course).

Comment: +1 You are right, the Intel iGPU is a part of the processor itself, so it shares the RAM with the processor, and there is little benefit in using it.

Comment: Just to add to the confusion in case someone reads this: there is also the [QE distribution based on the GPU-accelerated SIRIUS library](https://github.com/electronic-structure/q-e-sirius). CP2K is also interfaced with SIRIUS, so you can now run a GPU-accelerated QE (SIRUS) calculation through CP2K ;-)